# Can't checkout local branch using git plugin

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, phpstorm

For some reason I can't checkout local branch in IntelliJ IDEA (123.150) git plugin. I suspect I simply don't understand how it's supposed to work.

I thought that I have local branch if I cloned repo on my disk.

Here is what I did

- Created new project via "Check out from Version Control".
- IDEA shows I'm in git's master branch.
- If I click in right bottom corner on "Git: master" label it shows list of remote branches and no local branches
- If I click on remote `origin/master` and select `Checkout as new local branch` it gives me error saying `Branch name master already` exists.

I'm confused. Why it doesn't show any local branches ? If I don't have any why it doesn't let me create new one locally with name `master` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkout` is used for switching between branches or creating new ones in *your* repository. If you want to get the code from another repository, you need to use the `pull` or `fetch` commands. I don't know where these are in the IntelliJ plugin. I am simply using the names used at the command-line. Hopefully they will help you find what you need.